# IList, ICollection or IEnumerable in service interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a service for accessing my database with Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC 5. 
So I'm writing first a base service with his interface. But I'm worry about a little thing.

Usually I return an `IEnumerable<T>` in my interface, but that often leads to `ToList()` calls in the code.

So I was wondering what is the best to return in such an interface. 
I could just return `IList` but I'm afraid that it may be too much and that I won't need all of the methods provided with `IList`.

Here's my code :

```
public interface IBaseService<T>
{
    T Add(T obj);
    T Update(T obj);
    T Remove(string id);
    T Get(string id);

    ICollection<T> Find(Expression<Func<bool, T>> func);
    ICollection<T> GetAll();
}
```

Comment: So it depends what you want to do with that collection! If you only want people to be able to iterate it then use `IEnumerable` if you want people to be able to add items to it, remove items from it then use `IList` or `ICollection`

Comment: `IReadOnlyList<T>` maybe?

Comment: The only one I'd *not* use is `IEnumerable`, as it can lead to issues with left-over not-yet-computed queries, or callers nearly always calling `ToList()` or `ToArray()` to do something with the results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said that

> Usually I return an IEnumerable in my interface, but that often
>   leads to ToList() calls in the code.

You have to find out *why* you are calling `ToList()` on the results. It's possible, but unlikely, that you want to modify the result (add\remove items). It's generally not a good practice to return modifiable collection from methods like `Find` or `GetAll`, but you can return `ICollection<T>` or `IList<T>` (if you also need fast access via indexer or to insert\remove at specific positions).

However much more likely that you call to `ToList` to figure out how many elements are there and\or to access specific elements. If you need just `Count` - return `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` which extends `IEnumerable<T>` with just `Count` property. If you also need fast access via indexer - return `IReadOnlyList<T>` which extends `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` with indexer.

Both `Array` and `List<T>` implement all those interfaces so you can just return those classes as is:

```
 static IReadOnlyList<string> Test() {
      return new string[0]; // fine
 }
```

However, when returning `List` this way - caller might cast it back to `IList<T>` and still modify it. That's not a problem usually, but if you want to prevent that, use `AsReadOnly` on list (it will not copy anything to the new list so don't worry about perfomance):

```
static IReadOnlyList<string> Test() {
      return new List<string>().AsReadOnly(); // not required but good practice
 }
```

Comment: That's exactly the case, I often need to get specific element in the result or sort it in a special way with Linq/Lambda queries. 
So I think I'll go with `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` (as everybody here pointed out) for most of the cases. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `IReadOnlyCollection` will not help with "get specific element in the result", because this requires an indexer and it has none. You can use linq `ElementAt` but it will actually loop over whole collection until it gets to the target index, unless the real type you return as `IReadOnlyCollection` also implements `IList`. So if using fast access (via indexer) is important - you need to return `IList<T>`.

Comment: Ok so if I understood well, if I need Count property (for using the result in a foreach for example) I return `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` but if I need fast access via indexer I return `IList<T>`

Comment: Sorry I was a bit wrong with `IList<T>` in your case, because there is yet another interface - `IReadOnlyList<T>` which fits your scenario perfectly I think, because it has both Count and indexer, but is readonly. I updated my answer with it.

Comment: Even better ! Thanks a lot, it's clear as water now.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your intention. In most cases your return type should probably be `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`. In rare cases where you want the caller to be able to modify the collection, you can return `ICollection<T>`. Use `IEnumerable<T>` only if you are certain that the caller will only require forward iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the purest solution would be to go with `IEnumerable<T>`, but it comes down to setting a convention in your solution. If you're responsible for architecture, you might as well decide to return `List<T>` just to have the comfort of broader set of methods at hand.

Comment: Always return interfaces or an abstract type, never return an concrete implementation from a public method.